# Freely accessible collections of graph data

Tags: graph-theory

This question aims at providing links to definitions of graphs that either come from real-world problem or research that can be accessed and used freely; good examples in that vein are [TSPLIB95](http://comopt.ifi.uni-heidelberg.de/software/TSPLIB95/) or the [DIMACS Implementation challenges](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/programs/challenge/).

Besides the link answers should contain a description of the graphs that are defined like e.g. their origin, graph-theoretic properties and possible uses e.g. graph-theoretic problems for which the data can be used as testcases or benchmarks.

Comment: Related: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/739/data-for-testing-graph-algorithms

Answer (score 2):

A very extensive collection of graphs from real world problems is the [Stanford Large Network Dataset Collection](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/). The screenshot shows the graphs in the category "social networks", there are a dozen of other categories.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The **house of graphs** https://hog.grinvin.org/ contains a large number of graphs that are interesting for researchers in graph theory, with relevant graph parameters computed for each of the graphs (so you can also search for graphs satisfying a number of specific properties).

The meta-directory https://hog.grinvin.org/MetaDirectory also contains links to large lists of graphs of specific classes (for instance all planar graphs on at most 11 vertices...)

Answer (score 1):

In the same vein, I would also recommand the Konect database:
http://konect.cc/networks/
or networkrepository:
https://networkrepository.com/